# Removing the footer of page distorts the page. How to fix it?

Tags: html, css

I have written this piece of HTML code.

```
<style>
    .container { position:relative;}

    #sidebar {
        position:absolute;
        padding: 0.5%;
        top:0; bottom:0; left:0;
        width:20%;
        margin-left: 1.5%;
        margin-top: 7%;
        margin-bottom: 6.5%;
        background: #ff0;
    }

    #header { border:1px solid #000; width:100%; height:10%; 
        margin:0 0 5px 0;
    }

    #content { border:1px solid #000; width:77%; height:80%;
        position: absolute;
        margin-left: 23%;
    }
    #footer { border:1px solid #000; width:100%; height:10%;
        margin-top: 80%;
    }

    </style>
```

My HTML code is as follows:

```
<div class="container">
        <div id="sidebar">
            This is the siderbar of the page

<br><br>
                Select Gender
                <select name="gender">
                    <option value="">Select</option>
                    <option value="male">Male</option>
                    <option value="female">Female</option>
                </select>

            <hr>
            <label for="amount">Age range:</label>
            <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
            <div id="slider-range"></div>

</div>
<div id="header">
            <h1>This is the header of the page</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="content">

            This is content page..

        </div>  
        <div id="footer">This is the footer of the page..</div>
    </div>
```

When I remove `footer`, `.content` becomes too small. `sidebar` loses color. What wrong am I doing?

Comment: I dn't see any problem! https://jsfiddle.net/Lwjqp41n/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I remove footer, `.content` becomes smaller. Why?

Because `footer` makes content large by `margin-top: 80%;`

> I understand what you are talking about. What is the solution?

You use **percentage value** for `height` then give `height:100%;` to its parents because height with percentage value inherits from its parent and finally, remove `margin-top`.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/22zxzfLd/1/)

```css
html,
body,
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
#sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0.5%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 20%;
  margin-left: 1.5%;
  margin-top: 7%;
  margin-bottom: 6.5%;
  background: #ff0;
}
#header {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}
#content {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 77%;
  height: 80%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 23%;
}
#footer {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="sidebar">
    This is the siderbar of the page

    <br>
    <br>Select Gender
    <select name="gender">
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <option value="male">Male</option>
      <option value="female">Female</option>
    </select>

    <hr>
    <label for="amount">Age range:</label>
    <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
    <div id="slider-range"></div>

  </div>
  <div id="header">
    <h1>This is the header of the page</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="content">

    This is content page..

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I recommend you to use Html standard tags: `<header>`, `<footer>`.

Then, you have to work around `overflow` and `float` properties to get things to work.

```
overflow: hidden;
```

and

```
float: left;
```

Here is a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/kro55mtz/

Comment: Thanks David. I will use that it will help me from writing unnecessary css.